# Getting rails tests to reflect actual behaviour with FriendlyID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

The following class has only one mandatory relation and one validation

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

When testing an update

```
test "should update shop" do
  patch shop_url(@shop), params: { shop: { name: (@shop.name + "shh"), nation_id: @shop.nation_id } }
  assert_redirected_to shop_url(@shop)
end
```

will fail with

```
ShopsControllerTest#test_should_update_shop [/[...]/test/controllers/shops_controller_test.rb:48]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/shops/39503638> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/shops/bare-minimumshh>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/shops/39503638" to be === "http://www.example.com/shops/bare-minimumshh".
```

The first `Expected` is the designed behaviour so the testing expectation is wrong.

It's a bit of a conundrum because the controller defines, per FriendlyID requirement

```
@shop = Shop.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

whereas the test invokes in the setup

```
@shop = shops(:bare_minimum)
```

How can this test be written to take into account the (new) slug?

Comment: If you try calling `@shop.to_param` in your test does it return the slug as expected or the id? `assert_equal @shop.name + "shh", @shop.to_param`

Comment: `@shop.to_param` retruns the ID assigned by the test action.

Comment: Could it be tied to the fixture? Do you get the same behavior if you manually create a Shop instance? ‘assert_equal "foo", Shop.create!(name: "foo").to_param‘

Comment: Getting warm... no, the assertion suggested passed muster.  Upon modifying the fixture, a different failure complained `Couldn't find Shop with 'id'=bare-minimum-slug`.  Which pointed to the problem.  The problem lied with the  `before_action :set_shop, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]` Removing update from the before_action and setting `@shop = Shop.friendly.find(params[:id])` in said controller action resolved the failure. Hot.